# add and remove classes in order with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to say that, if my div doesnt have the class active add it. And if it does have the class active, remove it.

Ive the following, only my code adds the class, then continues the query and removes it at the end, what would the best solution be, 2 seperat click funcitons?

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    };
});
```

Comment: I see in your question you want a "toggle" effect on `.work-showcase` click event. @VisioN answwer seems the best to me. If you want to keep the class active on multiple clicks you'll need two buttons and separate the logic like @AbhijitPandya said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method:

```
$(".work-showcase").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
})
```

Comment: However way I add the class, when the function continues its going to remove it again isnt it?

Comment: Sorry I dont think ive explained my goal clearly enough @vision, ill update question

Comment: @Liam The current example toggles the class on click event.

Answer (score 0):

$("#YourID").removeClass('ClassName');
$("#YourID").addClass('ClassName');