# jquery on() with addClass/removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have this script which needs to work on an ipad. It was working on chrome with live, however, moving it to on makes it unresponsive.

Any ideas, I would be grateful!

```
$("#clickAll").on("click", function () {
    $(".welcome1poi").show();
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
$("#clickAll.active").on("click", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(".welcome1poi").hide();
});
```

Comment: If `#clickAll` is added to the DOM after that code runs, you need to delegate the event higher up the DOM tree. Read the [docs for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [add and remove classes in order with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481672/add-and-remove-classes-in-order-with-jquery)

Comment: There is no need for two events. Use toggleClass like the duplicate I just added and toggle to show and hide the other element!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you adding and removing the "active" class in order to create a toggle effect? If so, try .toggle(), like so:

```
$('#clickAll).toggle(
    function() { $('.welcome1poi').show(); }, 
    function() { $('.welcome1poi').hide(); });
```

Comment: [**toggle() event**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) has been deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9. I would not suggest to use it even with older versions of jQuery due to the reasons it was deprecated for.

Comment: Thanks, I dint know why I didn't think of this!

Comment: **THIS IS NOT THE CORRECT SOLUTION SINCE IT IS DEPRECATED!** ISSUE: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786. Feel free to use it and have your code stop woring when you upgrade jQuery versions. Or you can pick @bipen's solution using toggle and toggleClass and have it work.

Comment: OMG! But if you will continue to use an earlier version of jQuery this solution is just fine.

Comment: @JayBlanchard And I predict that in a few months time JamesB will be asking why this code no longer works. ;) Happens all the time around here. Do it right the first time and do not have to fix it in the future.

Comment: True, many people got caught with their pants down by using jquery-latest.js during the last round of CDN updates and the version went to 1.9

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$("#clickAll").on("click", function(){
    $(".welcome1poi").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

**updated**

**as suggested**

```
$(document).on('click',"#clickAll", function(){
    $(".welcome1poi").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

since it was working with live() i assume  your element with  id `clickAll` is added dynamically so try this

```
$(document).on("click","#clickAll", function () {
   $(".welcome1poi").show();
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
$(document).on("click","#clickAll.active", function () {
  $(this).removeClass("active");
   $(".welcome1poi").hide();
});
```

you can replace the `$(document)` selector with your closest element to `#clickAll` element which will be more efficient

Comment: Yeah, the problem is some items with the class welcome1poi will be open/closed before this is clicked...

Comment: that was not mentioned in the question so i showed you the easiest way to achieve ... however  if such is the case then i updated my answer....please check

Comment: your updated version... wouldn't both events trigger when `active` class has been added?

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. Thanks for your help and a little lesson in the syntax helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This will delegate the event to the `body` and it will be caught when it bubbles up the DOM.

```
$('body').on("click", "#clickAll", function(){
    $(".welcome1poi").show();
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
$('body').on("click", "#clickAll.active", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(".welcome1poi").hide();
});
```

Comment: There is no way to guarantee the event order there!

Comment: What event order are you talking about @epascarello?

Comment: Can you guarntee that the one with no class will not get called before the one with the class? They both apply to the same element. Plus the code is just reinventing toggle and toggleClass.

Comment: I just modified the OP's code and answered his original question. toggle() is deprecated in the newest version of jQuery